# jq json object concatenation to bash string array

Tags: json, bash, loops, key, jq

I want to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (or anything else when it's the wrong tool) to concatenate a json object like this:

```
{
  "https://github.com": {
    "user-one": {
      "repository-one": "version-one",
      "repository-two": "version-two"
    },
    "user-two": {
      "repository-three": "version-three",
      "repository-four": "version-four"
    }
  },
  "https://gitlab.com": {
    "user-three": {
      "repository-five": "version-five",
      "repository-six": "version-six"
    },
    "user-four": {
      "repository-seven": "version-seven",
      "repository-eight": "version-eight"
    }
  }
}
```

recursively to a bash string array like this:

```
(
    "https://github.com/user-one/repository-one/archive/refs/heads/version-one.tar.gz"
    "https://github.com/user-one/repository-two/archive/refs/heads/version-two.tar.gz"
    "https://github.com/user-two/repository-three/archive/refs/heads/version-three.tar.gz"
    "https://github.com/user-two/repository-four/archive/refs/heads/version-four.tar.gz"
    "https://gitlab.com/user-three/repository-five/-/archive/version-five/repository-five-version-five.tar.gz"
    "https://gitlab.com/user-three/repository-six/-/archive/version-six/repository-six-version-six.tar.gz"
    "https://gitlab.com/user-four/repository-seven/-/archive/version-seven/repository-seven-version-seven.tar.gz"
    "https://gitlab.com/user-four/repository-eight/-/archive/version-eight/repository-eight-version-eight.tar.gz"
)
```

for subsequent use in a loop.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Have no idea how to do that.
As you can see, the values must be handled differently depending on the object name.

```
"https://github.com" + "/" + $user_name + "/" + $repository_name + "/archive/refs/heads/" + $version + ".tar.gz"

"https://gitlab.com" + "/" + $user_name + "/" + $repository_name + "/-/archive/" + $version + "/" + $repository_name + "-" + $version + ".tar.gz"
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: The same techniques in the recently-answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891879/traversing-with-jq-yq/66891962#66891962 are what you need here.

Comment: ...thus, _ideally_, I would be closing this question as a duplicate, unless it explicitly asked a question that wasn't covered there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily done.

First, let's focus on the jq code alone:

```
to_entries[]                # split items into keys and values
| .key as $site             # store first key in $site
| .value                    # code below deals with the value
| to_entries[]              # split that value into keys and values
| .key as $user             # store the key in $user
| .value                    # code below deals with the value
| to_entries[]              # split that value into keys and values
| .key as $repository_name  # store the key in $repository_name
| .value as $version        # store the value in $version
| if $site == "https://github.com" then
    "\($site)/\($user)/\($repository_name)/archive/refs/heads/\($version).tar.gz"
  else
    "\($site)/\($user)/\($repository_name)/-/archive/\($version)/\($repository_name)-\($version).tar.gz"
  end
```

That generates a list of lines. Reading lines into a bash array looks like `readarray -t arrayname < ...datasource...`

Thus, using a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to redirect jq's stdout as if it were a file:

```sh
readarray -t uris < <(jq -r '
  to_entries[]
  | .key as $site
  | .value
  | to_entries[]
  | .key as $user
  | .value
  | to_entries[]
  | .key as $repository_name
  | .value as $version
  | if $site == "https://github.com" then
      "\($site)/\($user)/\($repository_name)/archive/refs/heads/\($version).tar.gz"
    else
      "\($site)/\($user)/\($repository_name)/-/archive/\($version)/\($repository_name)-\($version).tar.gz"
    end
  ' <config.json
)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I would never have figured that out on my own.

Comment: Filtering the various `$user`, `$repository_name`, `$version` with the `@url` filter would also ensure proper URL-Encoding.

Comment: @LéaGris - `@url` filter?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Glad to see the "Farewell to Trailing Pipes".

Comment: @peak I mean `@uri`. Like `( .key | @uri ) as $user`, `( .key | @uri ) as $repository_name` and `( .value | @uri ) as $version`. Then if one of these contains an URI prohibited character, it will be `%coded`. Example a a version of `"version-eight&nine"` will get encoded as `version-eight%26nine`

Answer (score 1):

The basic task of generating the strings can be done efficiently and generically (i.e., without any limits on the depths of the basenames) using the jq filter:

```
paths(strings) as $p | $p + [getpath($p)] | join("/")
```

There are several ways to populate a bash array accordingly, but if you merely wish to iterate through the values, you could use a bash `while` loop, like so:

```
< input.json jq -r '
  paths(strings) as $p | $p + [getpath($p)] | join("/")' | 
  while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line"
  done
```

You might also wish to consider using jq's @sh or @uri filter.  For a jq urlencode function, see e.g.
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_encoding#jq

(If the strings contain newlines or tabs, then the above would need to be tweaked accordingly.)